# Help connecting a domain and my server

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I have a ubuntu server and also I have a domain when I run the serve in LAN (Local Area Network)
it works perfectly, but over WAN it cant connect to the server. I have deactivate the firewall from the router and the server. Not advisable.

However, when I ping the ip and the domain it seems to be responding. 
what are the files that have to be configured on apache2. 
Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Look whenever you are setting up a domain on a server, you need NS1 & NS2 name server.

These entries you will make using BIND service on your Server. Now These NS1 & NS2 need to be added with your registered domain from where domain is purchased. then it will take 2-48 hours to propagates through network to be available.

Here NS1 & NS2 use to Bind the IP Address with your domain Name.

Try doing this. i think it will help you.

Comment: I have done that. Do you want to look at my interfaces and resolv.conf ?

Comment: for help u can refer my Blog cum note http://sumantjsr.blogspot.in/2011/10/dns-server-setup-using-bind-dns-on_5567.html. i did the same for my case & it was working.